# Create Buttons with only Javascript

Tags: javascript, interaction

I've been trying to create a basic card game. The idea is that it shows you cards, and you click on a button and it flips the card or changes color or whatever. Im doing this for school, so I'm doing this on a site called codehs.com that has its own javascript editor.

https://codehs.com/share/8xBGa1CKkI4paE35nY9x
(link to the site)

The problem is that as far as i can tell, the only way to actually create a button is with html, and have it interact with javascript through a webpage. This is a problem because I don't know how to do this with javascript alone.

My question is, is there any way to create a button as an object in a Javascript without, without any html?

first time asking, sorry if this isn't the best way of asking
Thanks in advance (and those who've answered, i appreciate the help)

Comment: You can create the button with JavaScript, but to place it into the document in a particular place, you need an HTML element to use as a target.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how would i make it with the javascript? I guess thats my basic question

Comment: Any particular reason you are using this site instead of a more general-purpose site? Or even developing locally?  This one seems like a special purpose site for a purpose I couldn't quite fathom...

Comment: Its for a computer science class. I agree its much more limiting, but this is what the teacher wants. I did try to do it by writing as html in a text document, but really slowed me down :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the environment you are talking about -- a link there would really help, but assuming you at least have access to the DOM, it is easy enough to create a button via JavaScript.

```js
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "click me!";

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  button.innerHTML = "You did it";
});

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```